# SQL for sort within group show top within group in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in Postgres that has data like this:

```
fk | priority | date
1       1       4-1-2023
1       1       4-3-2023
1       2       4-5-2023
2       3       4-1-2023
2       2       4-2-2023
3       3       4-6-2023
```

I need the results to be this:

```
fk | priority | date
1       1       4-3-2023
2       2       4-2-2023
3       3       4-6-2023
```

So within each grouping of fk I want the highest priority. 1 being the highest. And if there is a priority tie then I want the most recent date.

My SQL is not this advanced and I am having a hard time finding a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with either a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) with a subquery (works for multiple RDBMS)

```sql
SELECT fk, priority, mydate
FROM (
    SELECT *, /* Return all the columns we want in the final query */
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk ORDER BY priority, mydate DESC) AS rn
        /* 
            Generate a row number, 
            restarting the numbering for each `fk` value seen (partition by)
            Order the rows, first: the smallest number `priority` (ascending),
            then: the latest `mydate` (descending)
            Put the result in a column named `rn` to use in the outer query
        */
    FROM mytable
) x
WHERE rn = 1 /* Filter by the `rn` value, return only the first row */
;
```

Or with a `DISTINCT ON` [clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) (more postgresql specific)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fk) * /* Return a distinct row for each fk value */
FROM mytable
ORDER BY fk, priority, mydate DESC 
/* 
    Order by which is the first row to return 
    It is required to include `fk` first because of the DISTINCT ON (fk), 
    but then: get the smallest `priority` (ascending),
    then: the latest `mydate` (descending).
*/
;
```

Comment: Seeing the question has a postgresql tag, the second option is definitly the way to go

Comment: Thanks, ROW_NUMBER did the trick. I had completely forgotten about this method.